# Protect access to VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have an `.xlsm` file with private features (sheets and VBA code) that I want to share with external people. Using a VBA function, I want to restrict their access to only specific sheets (which I have already done *via* the `Sheet.Protect` method), but I also want to prevent them from accessing and running the VBA code (which, by the way, contains the password to unlock all the sheets).

How can I block them from accessing the VBA code and running the macros?

I thought that users couldn't access VBA code in a protected workbook, but this is actually not the case: I already tried to protect the workbook itself but the VBA code is still accessible.
Is there a solution to do it using VBA?
(To be very specific, I'd like to create a macro in my file that prevents users from accessing all my macros, unless they enter the password)

And subsidiary question: is it the right way to protect a workbook through a password which is stored in a macro in this very same workbook? In the hypothesis I can limit the access to VBA code, is it safe?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: You can password-protect the VB project to hide the code, but you should be aware that anyone who really wants to can easily Google for how to bypass your protection.

Comment: Thanks! Two remarks:
(1) If I password-protect the VB project, users can still run my macros, which is something I don't want them to
(2) I'd like to be able to perform this operation using macros, while password-protect the project needs to be done manually

Comment: Seems like you should be sharing a macro-free version then?  You can extract the code into a separate workbook and still have it work on the shared one...

Comment: Yes I think it might be the best solution, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: But you should know, that the protection of the sheets are also easily removed. But anyway a macro free version of the workbook has only advantages, if you don't need the macros for the user.